# A length-$30$ string made of $\{1,\dots,6\}$ with sum $48$ has a substring with sum $11$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I found this problem in some "Warmup" set of Canadian olympiad problem set:

> The doctor instructed a person to take 48 pills for next 30 days. Every day he takes at least 1 pill and at most 6 pills. Show that there is some number of consecutive days such that the total numbers of pills he takes within those days is equal to 11.

In terms of variables: $x_1+x_2\cdots +x_{30}=48$ and $1\leq x_n \leq 6$.

If we define partial sums $s_n = \displaystyle \sum_{i \leq n} x_i$, the differences $s_n-s_m$ represent pills eaten in consecutive days.

How does one approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p_i$ be the number of pills consumed after $i$ days, $1 \leq i \leq 30$.  Since the person consumes at least one pill each day, the sequence $(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{30})$ is strictly increasing.  Moreover, $1 \leq p_1 < p_2 < \ldots < p_{30} = 48$.

Let $q_i = p_i + 11$, $1 \leq i \leq 30$.  Then the sequence $(q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_{30})$ is also strictly increasing and $12 \leq q_1 < q_2 < \ldots < q_{30} = 59$.

Notice that the $60$ numbers $\{p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{30}, q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_{30}\}$ are positive integers less than or equal to $59$.  Therefore, at least two of them must be equal.  Since the sequences $(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{30})$ and $(q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_{30})$ are each strictly increasing, there must be some $p_i = q_j$, where $j < i$.  Since $q_j = p_j + 11$, it follows that the patient takes exactly $11$ pills over the stretch of days $p_{j + 1}, p_{j + 2}, \ldots, p_i$.

Comment: Gorgeous solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the numbers $s_1, s_2, \dots, s_{12}$ modulo $11$. By Pigeonhole principle two of these are equal and hence their difference is divisible by $11$. Similarly for $s_{13}, s_{14}, \dots, s_{24}$. So among $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{24}$ you can find at least two disjoint blocks whose sums are divisible by $11$.

Neither of these two blocks can be $0$ since they are positive.

Can both of these blocks be $\geq 22$? No, since then the total number of all pills in the $30$ days would be at least $$2\times22 + 1\times (30-2\times 12) = 50 > 48$$

Therefore at least one of them actually equals $11$ and we're done.